# cannot install package OpenMx in R

Tags: r, openmx

I'm running R version 3.5 on a mac.
When I try to install OpenMx by

```
install.packages("OpenMx")
```

it eventually fails after a bunch of warning messages.

At first the warning message was

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

and found out this could be handled by running

```
xcode-select --install
```

on Terminal.

When I tried installing OpenMx after installing xcode,

the last several lines of messages are:

```
optimize.c:35:15: warning: unused function 'f_bound' [-Wunused-function]
static double f_bound(int n, const double *x, void *data_)
              ^
optimize.c:51:15: warning: unused function 'f_noderiv' [-Wunused-function]
static double f_noderiv(int n, const double *x, void *data_)
              ^
optimize.c:57:15: warning: unused function 'f_direct' [-Wunused-function]
static double f_direct(int n, const double *x, int *undefined, void *data_)
              ^
optimize.c:79:21: warning: unused function 'initial_step' [-Wunused-function]
static nlopt_result initial_step(nlopt_opt opt, const double *x, double *step)
                    ^
optimize.c:101:12: warning: unused function 'finite_domain' [-Wunused-function]
static int finite_domain(unsigned n, const double *lb, const double *ub)
           ^
5 warnings generated.
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/BH/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rpf/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c options.c -o options.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c sadmvn.f -o sadmvn.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [sadmvn.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘OpenMx’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/OpenMx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenMx’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/f8/y98w5w9n3yz3sq2pthhw35xm0000gn/T/RtmpJtQ01E/downloaded_packages’
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I just had the same issue, I resolved it by installing the `gfortran` compiler.  Not sure whether to mark this as duplicate or not: The issue is with missing `gfortran`, which is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44228394/2799941).  But I found this post looking for the same OpenMx error as OP, and the post I've linked to isn't OpenMx specific.  It still might be worth keeping this one open for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install.packages("OpenMx") should just work for all platforms under R 3.5
It's possible you tried before CRAN had finished pushing out new binary builds for all platforms. Jut try again now.

If you want to build from source (**not necessary**) you would need to install the whole MacOS toolchain for R >= 3.4 provided [at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org).

Answer (score 2):

This is the key error message:

> make: gfortran: No such file or directory

You need to install a `gfortran` compiler.  You can find compilers and download/installation instructions here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries.

(Note: This solution is also provided in response to a different R package, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228394/installing-samr-in-in-r-3-4).)