# In R, how can I plot the standardised loadings of a CFA model ('Std.all' column in lavaan output) instead of the estimated loadings?

Tags: r-lavaan

When using the lavaan package in R, I fit a CFA model:

```
# Load libraries:
library(dplyr)
library(lavaan)

# Create variables:
var1 <- 
  rnorm(10, 5, 1)

var2 <- 
  rnorm(10, 5, 1)

var3 <- 
  rnorm(10, 5, 1)

# Create dataframe:
df <-
  tibble(var1, var2, var3)

# Define CFA model:
latent_var <-
  "latent_var =~ var1 + var2 + var3"

# Fit CFA model, ignoring warnings:
cfa_mod <-
  cfa(latent_var, df)

# Summarise, specifying standardised factor loadings:
summary(cfa_mod, standardized = TRUE)
```

However, when I want to plot (I've been using lavaanPlot), there seems to be no way to specify that I want the standardised loadings from the 'Std.all' column rather than the estimated loadings from the 'Estimate' column:

```
# Load libraries:
library(lavaanPlot)

# Plot model, specifying coefficient labels:
lavaanPlot(model = cfa_mod, coefs = TRUE)
```

I've played about with the 'edge_options =' argument, hoping to find some way of specifying standardised loadings, but no success (the documentation seems to suggest that this argument is aesthetic, for setting colours etc.). How can I plot the 'Std.all' column from the lavaan output instead of the 'Estimate' column, using lavaanPlot (or any other plotting package)?

Comment: It is an easy option in the `semPlot` package: http://sachaepskamp.com/semPlot/examples#Lavaan

Comment: Thanks very much. Sadly, I'm unable to install semPlot due to an inability to install a package called OpenMx. The issue is discussed at length here (https://github.com/OpenMx/OpenMx/issues/238), here (https://openmx.ssri.psu.edu/node/4239), and here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014226/cannot-install-package-openmx-in-r), but sadly these fixes are beyond my skills as a programmer. +1, though, and hopefully anyone else coming here will be able to install and use semPlot to plot their standardised factor loadings!

Answer (score 2):

> I've been using `lavaanPlot`, there seems to be no way to specify that I want the standardised loadings from the `Std.all` column

There is, but it is not showing on the `?lavaanPlot` help page because the option is passed via `...` to the `buildPaths()` function.  If you look up the latter's help page, you will find the `stand=TRUE` option will plot standardized paths.  This is also shown in the package's `vignette("Intro_to_lavaanPlot", package = "lavaanPlot")`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/vignettes/Intro_to_lavaanPlot.html

Comment: Thanks @Terrence. Solved my problem and good advice generally for a new(ish) R user that not all arguments are contained in the help page